# Concatenating multiple columns to create another column

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` with two columns (the "EYE" and "ID"); I want to `mute` the third column  "EYE_ID" by combining elements of the first and the second by separating them with the underscore sign `_`.

```
df <- tibble::tibble(ID = replicate(5, 'GATE'),
                     EYE = seq(1, 5, 1))
```

**What I Want**

I want a result like this:

```
ID      EYE     EYE_ID
  <chr> <dbl>   <chr>
1 GATE      1   GATE_1
2 GATE      2   GATE_2
3 GATE      3   GATE_3
4 GATE      4   GATE_4
5 GATE      5   GATE_5
```

Comment: `df %>%unite(EYE_ID, ID, EYE, remove = FALSE)`

Answer (score -1):

USE `unite` from tidyr:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  unite(EYE_ID, ID, EYE, remove = FALSE)

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  EYE_ID ID      EYE
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
1 GATE_1 GATE      1
2 GATE_2 GATE      2
3 GATE_3 GATE      3
4 GATE_4 GATE      4
5 GATE_5 GATE      5
```

or even `str_c`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(EYE_ID = str_c(ID, EYE, sep = '_'))

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  ID      EYE EYE_ID
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1 GATE      1 GATE_1
2 GATE      2 GATE_2
3 GATE      3 GATE_3
4 GATE      4 GATE_4
5 GATE      5 GATE_5
```

In base R you could use:

```
transform(df, EYE_ID = paste(ID, EYE, sep = '_'))
    ID EYE EYE_ID
1 GATE   1 GATE_1
2 GATE   2 GATE_2
3 GATE   3 GATE_3
4 GATE   4 GATE_4
5 GATE   5 GATE_5
```